# how to read values from web.config in javascript in aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-config, identifier

I have a javascript code in the aspx file.

In my script function, I am trying to read the 'SiteRootURL' value from the web.config as:

```
var k = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteRootURL"].ToString() %>'
     alert(k);
```

This is not working. When I add above code, I get blue squirkly lines at the top of my aspx page - <%@Page...%> which says - Identifier Expected'

When I remove the above line, the code runs fine. Please help me. What am I doing wrong? How can I read the value form the web.config in javascript.

Comment: PLease let us know how you solved this problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function on your code behind file like this:

```
protected static string GetAppSettingsValue()
{
    return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SiteRootURL").ToString();
}
```

And then call it on your javascript like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('<%=GetAppSettingsValue%>');
</script>
```

Comment: I dont see the error. When I run the application and go that page. I see a custom application error page.